# Google Analytics 4 PHP library not returning any property list

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Why is the Google Analytics 4 PHP library not returning any property list even though I have enabled Google Analytics permissions in my service account.

$properties=$analytics>management_webproperties>listManagementWebproperties(accountID)
$properties->getItems()

return empty list . but in my GA account there have a GA4 property and given all necessary permission in service account

I have followed https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-php

this documentation